# Composer problem on LAMP Droplet Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I want to use nexmo platform so I created the LAMP droplet from DigitalOcean.
There is no problem at this point.
After then ı installed composer on [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04) page.

Lastly When I want to install nexmo with this command,

```
composer require nexmo/client
```

it was installed but when ı added this code on my `index.php` file

```
require_once _DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Page does not load.

Here my directory...

```
var/www/html/index.php

var/www/html/vendor
```

What's the problem can anyone help me please?

I search the problem on the Internet and I tried some solution but it's wasn't change anything.

`composer install - composer update`, etc... I tried these.

Answer (score 0):

If your `index.php` and `vendor` folder are at the same path, then your `require_once` is wrong. It needs to be:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

`__DIR__` resolves to the directory where the current file is located, so the `vendor` folder is actually located at `__DIR__ . '/vendor/'`.

Comment: Are you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.